# Trying to download files using express and node js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, adm-zip

Here is my block of code.

```
app.get('/download/:id', async(req,res) =>{
    const {id} = req.params;
    const staffDoc = await Staff.findById(id);
    var to_zip = fs.readdirSync(__dirname + `/uploads/${staffDoc.profile}`);
    const zip = new admzip();
        for(let i = 0; i < to_zip.length;i++){
            zip.addLocalFile(to_zip[i])
        };

        const file_after_download = 'downloaded_file.zip';

        const data = zip.toBuffer();

        res.set('Content-Type', 'application/octet-stream');
        res.set('Content-Disposition', `attachment; filename=${file_after_download}`);
        res.set('Content-Length', data.length);
        res.send(data);
    
});
```

I made a site that at the moment you can upload files but it will be stored on the local directory '/uploads'
[The local directory the files are stored](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RY47q.png)
But files will name/id will be stored on mongodb in an array named profile.
[how the files name are stored in mongodb](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fziET.png)
Now I'm trying to download certain files based on their name/id stored in the array profile. But it doesnt work it keepson giving me an error
[the error i keep getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tDfd0.png)

I've also tried:

```
const x = __dirname+"/uploads/";
            res.zip([
                 {
                   path : x + staffDoc.profile[0],
                    name : staffDoc.profile[0]
                }
             ])
```

This worked but i can't seem to wrap a loop around it so I'll be able to download all the files and don't know anyother way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `map`

```
res.zip(
  staffDoc.profile.map((p) => ({
    path: x + p,
    name: p,
  })),
);
```

Comment: thank you worked perfectly but u mistakenly typed profile twice but thank you

Comment: i have another issue. Now i want to to be able to select a single file from staffDoc.profile and download it.